# Zero in double vs char* ambiguity

Tags: c++

I have a handy class in C++ that can be initialized either with an `double` or with a `char*`. Everything works as expected except one case when the argument is zero.

```
struct Var {
    Var (double src) {}
    Var (char *src) {}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Var A = 123;
    Var B = "abc";
    Var C = 0; <- Error: conversion from 'int' to 'Var' is ambiguous
}
```

Previously I used `int` instead of `double`, and it was fine for some reason.

How can this be fixed?

PS: I know I can use `(double)0` or just `0.0`, but is there a way to allow just `0` to be accepted as **double**?

Comment: Have you tried adding a constructor that accepts an `int`, calling the `double`-constructor?

Comment: In `C++` the `0` can be either an *integer zero* or a *null pointer*. The recent `C++11` standard addresses that by introducing the keyword `nullptr` for the *null pointer*.

Comment: @Galik: Sort of.  It's still true that `0` is ambiguous.

Answer (score 11):

You could eliminate the ambiguity by adding a third constructor which takes an `int` and delegates to the `double` version (requires C++11):

```
struct Var {
    Var (double src) {}
    Var (const char *src) {}
    //   ^^^^^ should be const
    Var (int src) : Var {static_cast<double>(src)} {}
};
```

However, this could be solved easier by changing your `char*` constructor to take a `std::string` instead and using direct initialization.

Comment: Well, who knows whether using `std::string` is acceptable... The first alternative is certainly good, if that's the way it should be resolved.

Answer (score 7):

In C++, the literal `0` has type int. You cannot change anything about it being an integer, without adding at least a decimal point. (no actual need to write digits after the point though)

To answer you implicit question regarding why the call was unambiguous with `123` but ambiguous with `0`:

- When you initialized `A`, it was fine because there is no implicit conversion from an int to a pointer (`char*`, in this case).
- When you initialized `C` using an int the second time, you used `0`, the literal `0` can be implicitly converted to a pointer (some legacy behaviour, before C++11 offered `nullptr` literal).

So, in a nutshell:

```
int * a = 0; // legal;
int * b = 2; // ILLEGAL;
```

When initializing `C` one conversion is needed to give the argument to any of the two available constructors (and both conversions have the same ranking), the call is ambiguous.

To make it unambiguous, you should either cast your int literal to a double (`(double)0`), use a double literal (`0.`), or add a constructor taking an int.
With this last solution, the constructor taking an `int` is an exact match, so it is a better match that another overload requiring a conversion (which is why it would be selected).

Edit. Please note that **TartanLlama** answer should be accepted here as it is a best C++ practice: the constructor taking an C-style string should take a `std::string` instead. Since there is an implicit conversion from C-style string to `std::string`, the call will work with little change:

```
Var B("abc");
```

But you will isolate your class interface from pointers details.

Comment: Re "The literal 0 has type int". What about the null pointer? And pure virtual functions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: The null pointer involves a conversion, so it's ranked worse during overload resolution than a direct match to `int`.  Pure virtual functions have nothing to do with a literal `0`, the grammar doesn't accept a literal there, only the token sequence `= 0`.  (For example, `0x0` is also an integer literal zero, and also converts to a null pointer, but is unacceptable in a pure-specifier)